# What is the setting to require Entity Framework automatic database schema creation?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

If you're developing against SQL CE and using the Entity Framework Code First, the schema is created on the fly by default. But what about SQL Express or SQL Server proper?

What is the setting - either in code or Web.Config - to enable automatic schema creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic is just used provider

SQL Server CE connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Context" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
       connectionString="Data Source=File.sdf" />
</connectionStrings>
```

SQL Server connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Context" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
       connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
</connectionStrings>
```